# How to take input of every next line from console in java ? I have made a code but it's not giving the desired output

Tags: java

I want to take the input from the console like as follows:

```
3(int type)
1(int type)
4(int type)
1100(String type)
1010(String type)
0000(String type)
```

My Code is as follows :

```
int numberOfFriends = sc.nextInt();
int forbidden = sc.nextInt();
int binaryOptions = sc.nextInt();
String[] friendsOrder = new String[numberOfFriends];
System.out.println(numberOfFriends);
System.out.println(forbidden);
System.out.println(binaryOptions);
for(int j=0;j<numberOfFriends;j++)
{
    friendsOrder[j] = sc.nextLine();
}
for(int j=0;j<numberOfFriends;j++)   
{
    System.out.println(friendsOrder[j]);
}
```

but it's output is :

```
3
1
4

1100
1010
```

It's not printing all the string inputs, besides its printing null why so?

Comment: How is this even compile? where `i` in `friendsOrder[i]` is coming from?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience i have edited the question now.

Comment: @Guy can you suggest some solutions now?

Comment: There are already 5 answers, there is nothing more I can add.

Comment: ok thank you i got my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
for(int j=0;j<numberOfFriends;j++)
{
   friendsOrder[i] = sc.nextLine();
}
```

to

```
for(int i=0;i<numberOfFriends;i++)
{
   friendsOrder[i] = sc.nextLine();
}
```

as looping over **j** and using **i** as index inside the loop makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

After 3rd `sc.nextInt()` you will have to use an extra `sc.nextLine()` to go to the next line. From there use `sc.nextLine()` to read your 3 lines.

**Updated code**

```
int numberOfFriends = sc.nextInt();
int forbidden = sc.nextInt();
int binaryOptions = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine(); // extra sc.nextLine call

String[] friendsOrder = new String[numberOfFriends];
System.out.println(numberOfFriends);
System.out.println(forbidden);
System.out.println(binaryOptions);
for(int j=0;j<numberOfFriends;j++)
{
    friendsOrder[j] = sc.nextLine(); // there is also a small mistake here, use j instead of i
}
for(int j=0;j<numberOfFriends;j++)   
{
    System.out.println(friendsOrder[j]);
}
```

Whats happening is after 3rd `sc.nextInt()`, the next call to `sc.nextLine()` reads the same line which contains 3rd integer till the end of line.

Answer (score -1):

Scanner.nextLine() read up to the first newline character('\n'). After reading the int, '\n' is still in the stream and hence on the first run of your for loop, nextLine() method is reading that '\n' character and returns. You have to call newLine() again to read the entered string. The updated code will be:

```
int numberOfFriends = sc.nextInt();
int forbidden = sc.nextInt();
int binaryOptions = sc.nextInt();
String[] friendsOrder = new String[numberOfFriends];
System.out.println(numberOfFriends);
System.out.println(forbidden);
System.out.println(binaryOptions);
for(int j=0;j<numberOfFriends;j++)
{
    sc.nextLine();
    friendsOrder[i] = sc.nextLine();
}
for(int j=0;j<numberOfFriends;j++)     
{
    System.out.println(friendsOrder[j]);
}
```

Comment: it's not working correctly brother now it's not printing any string.

Comment: Hi, @Abhishek welcome to SO. Your loop does reads 2 line in 1 iteration. This is wrong. Extract that extra `sc.nextLine()` outside.